# OS mouse cursors

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, mouse

I'm surprised that the options that come with MouseCursor class doesn't comprehend the resize and the move cursors, so, I was thinking, is there any way to retrieve the OS version of those?, or do I have to make a custom mouse cursor?.

Thanks.

Comment: Custom cursors are your best bet.

Comment: Yeah I already implemented them using custom cursors, but I found strange that there were no other options besides the basics.